# Is it possible to read RDD from spark.local.dir, if no then what are the other possible ways to persist and then read those RDD's?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am reading data from a stream and then working on that data. I have multiple projects that read the same stream and then use it. 
So, I don't want to read the same stream again and again, and want to create a single project that read from stream and then persist the RDD's.
Then in all the other projects I can just read the data from those persisted RDD's.

Is it possible to read RDD from spark.local.dir, if yes then how, if no then what are the other possible ways to persist and then read those RDD's ?

Was thinking of persisting in textFiles also, but don't know how to persist objects, and how to deal with the huge amount of files. If there is a way to set TTL for those generated files then please share.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0):

Persist it to Tachyon. http://tachyon-project.org. Use saveAsObjectFile("tachyon://tachyon-master:19998/some/path") or if it is a data frame then you could use parquet format instead of object file.

Cleaning old files is a different issue. Perhaps a cron job would suffice?